# Trigger an event on an element from another element in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a div and a file input box. When we click on the div, the click of file input is to be triggered. How to do this in vue.js?

Comment: You can do it with html element label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to access the DOM to trigger the click event for the input.

But Vue can make it pretty convenient with the `ref`/`$refs` [feature](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)

With it, you can "mark" an element in the template and access it conveniently from within your component's code without relying on selectors.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    clickHandler() {
      this.$refs.fileInput.click()
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.3/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="button" @click="clickHandler">Click me!</div>
  <input type="file" ref="fileInput">
</div>
```

Comment: Oops you were 3 sec late

Comment: Please always include some explanation of your code when you answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, edited my answer. Is that better?

Comment: Why it does not works with a dropdown <select>, instead of a <input> ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ref` to you input and a click listener to your wrapper `div`

```
<div @click="triggerFileInput" id="wrapper">
    <input type="file" ref="myFile">
</div>


methods:{
    triggerFileInput(){
        this.$refs.myFile.click();
    }
}
```