# Call method from another vue.js component through this.$refs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I have a sibling element which i want to trigger.

[i've try this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44328457/10880162)

```
<b-img @click="callFileLoader"/>
<b-file type="file" ref="fileUploader"></b-file>
...

methods:{
  callFileLoader () {
    this.$refs.fileUploader.click()
  }
}
```

Got: Uncaught TypeError: this.$refs.fileUploader.click is not a function

[b-file documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-file)

Comment: That means that b-file it is not clickable

Comment: First check if BFile component is clickable then try this: `this.$refs.fileUploader.$el.click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging i found a way to access that input using this statement :

```
   this.$refs.fileUploader.$el.firstChild
```

which is `<input>` element that could be clickable.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      file: null,
      file2: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    callFileLoader() {

      this.$refs.fileUploader.$el.firstChild.click();

    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.0.0-rc.11/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<div id='app'>

  <div>
    <!-- Styled -->

    <b-file v-model="file" ref="fileUploader" :state="Boolean(file)" placeholder="Choose a file..."></b-file>
    <div class="mt-3">Selected file: {{file && file.name}}</div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="callFileLoader">load</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Props to this guy

Answer (score 1):

If it is sibling component, it is not recognized in sibling component via v-ref approach. 
Either try to access it via parent component or Vue root, if there is no parent component where it is nested:

```
 this.$root.$refs.fileUploader.click()
```

Or use `this.$root.$emit()` in sibling component `b-img`, to trigger event, and place event listener in `events` of `b-file` component to catch emited event and trigger `click`

so in b-img would be:

```
methods:{
  callFileLoader () {
    this.$root.$emit('file-uploader-click');
  }
}
```

and in `b-file` would be:

```
events:{
  'file-uploader-click' : function() {
    this.click();
  }
}
```

Instead of placing events method, you try to place `v-on:event-name="action"` within an component:

VueTools chrome extension is very useful to check correct reference name generated by VueJs

Comment: those components are not mine so i can't change them

Comment: then try to call click by placing v-on within component  instance you have placed, and please change your question to mention that these components cannot be edited :)

Comment: Thanks! The docs are extremely unclear about what the scope is of $refs. I didn't understand how to get to $refs of a different component. This is how I did it:  this.$parent.$refs.notesComponent.$refs.notes.focus()